# How to successfully copy InnoDB tables to another Linux installation?

Tags: mysql

Because I could no longer log into my Linux Mint system, I installed another Ubuntu system alongside of it to just continue working, but I'm having problems transferring the databases.

According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-migration.html), if I understood it correctly, InnoDB tables should be just as easy to transfer as the MyISAM ones. However, my InnoDB files are not accessible with the message `Unable to select the table: Table 'tw.categories' doesn't exist`, even though they do show up in my tables list. MyISAM tables work properly.

I have changed the file permissions and user/group ownership to the same ones as on the previous system, which are saned/sambashare. But weirdly enough, when I change the user/group ownership of the whole directory to the same one as on the previous system, then I can no longer see the list of tables in the database. I have to leave those on mysql/root if I want to see them (and keep access to the MyISAM tables).

Then, I have changed the file permissions and user/group ownership to the same ones as new test tables that are created on this system, which is mysql/root for the directory and mysql/mysql for the files inside. It didn't change anything.

Any alternative solution appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The ibdata and the ib_log files needed to be copied as well.